# How to select a specific viewport to transform, while keeping the previous transformations in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2015

So this is for an assignment that I'm supposed to do, where the guidelines that I'm currently focusing on are :

 The user can select the “active” viewport by clicking on it (you should change the color of the
border when a viewport is selected). Any transformation (rotation, translation, etc…) should be
performed on the active viewport only.

 User should be able to navigate the scene in the selected viewport using WASD keys and/or arrow
keys (for ortho projections). Mouse control (like in an FPS game) and WASD keys and/or arrows
for the perspective projection. Navigation should be allowed only in the active viewport. The
other viewports should remain static.

I already have code that can transform the perspective view in fps fashion, and hardcoded some camera transformations for the front view, but I can't seem to figure out how to make a function or something that can differentiate between the viewports, cause if I could I would be able to just insert the code for transforming into that. I'm currently using a mouseclickcallbackfunction to detect where the mouse is, but the main problem being it runs after my displaycallbackfunction, which is where viewports are created and run, thus meaning i have to find a way to make it so i can transform from the display funciton instead of the mouse one detecting it.

some of my code is this:

```
void DisplayCallbackFunction(void)
{
/* clear the screen */
glViewport(0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight);
glClearColor(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 0.8f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();

//create viewport
setViewport(1);

//Perspective
//glFrustum(-1.0f,1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 100);
gluPerspective(45.0f,1.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f);

//Orthographic
//glOrtho(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0f, 100.0f);
//gluOrtho2D(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);


glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
/*
if (x < windowWidth / 2 && y < windowHeight / 2) {

    viewport = 3;
    std::cout << "Viewport =" << viewport << std::endl;
}
if (x > windowWidth / 2 && y < windowHeight / 2) {
    viewport = 4;
    std::cout << "Viewport =" << viewport << std::endl;
}
if (x > windowWidth / 2 && y > windowHeight / 2) {
    viewport = 2;
    std::cout << "Viewport =" << viewport << std::endl;
}
if (x < windowWidth / 2 && y > windowHeight / 2) {
    viewport = 1;
    std::cout << "Viewport =" << viewport << std::endl;
}
break;*/

    gluLookAt(
        cameraPosition.x, cameraPosition.y, cameraPosition.z,// camera position
        cameraPosition.x + forwardVector.x,
        cameraPosition.y + forwardVector.y,
        cameraPosition.z + forwardVector.z,// what the camera is looking at 
        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);//what the camera thinks is up


/* This is where we draw things */
//glColor3f(0.5f, 0.8f, 0.1f); //RGB  or 4f-> RGBA
//drawObjects();


//cube code is here




//second viewport
setViewport(2);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();


gluLookAt(
    rz, rz2, 6.0f,// camera position
    rz, rz2, 0.0f,// what the camera is looking at 
    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);//what the camera thinks is up



//other cube

//third viewport
setViewport(3);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
gluLookAt(
    -6.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,// camera position
    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,// what the camera is looking at 
    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);//what the camera thinks is up
//3rd cube

//fourth viewport
setViewport(4);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
gluLookAt(
    0.0f, 6.0f, 0.0f,// camera position
    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,// what the camera is looking at 
    0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);//what the camera thinks is up

//fourth cube

//HUD or Overlay viewport

glViewport(0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glColor4f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glVertex3f(-0.02, -1.0, 0.0);// bottom left
glVertex3f(0.02, -1.0, 0.0); //bottom right
glVertex3f(0.02, 1.0, 0.0); // top right
glVertex3f(-0.02, 1.0, 0.0); // top left
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glVertex3f(-1.0, -0.02, 0.0);// bottom left
glVertex3f(1.0, -0.02, 0.0); //bottom right
glVertex3f(1.0, 0.02, 0.0); // top right
glVertex3f(-1.0, 0.02, 0.0); // top left
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);// bottom left
glVertex3f(0.02, 0.0, 0.0); //bottom right
glVertex3f(0.02, 1.0, 0.0); // top right
glVertex3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0); // top left
glEnd();

/* Swap Buffers to Make it show up on screen */
glutSwapBuffers();
}
void KeyboardCallbackFunction(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
std::cout << "Key Down:" << (int)key << std::endl;



switch (key)
{
case 32: // the space bar
    break;
case 27: // the escape key
//case 'q': // the 'q' key
    exit(0);
    break;
case 'W':
case 'w':
    cameraPosition += (forwardVector * movementScalar);
    break;
case 'S':
case 's':
    cameraPosition -= (forwardVector * movementScalar);
    break;
case 'A':
case 'a':
    rightVector = glm::cross(forwardVector, glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
    rightVector = glm::normalize(rightVector);
    cameraPosition -= (rightVector * movementScalar);
        break;
case 'D':
case 'd':
    rightVector = glm::cross(forwardVector, glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
    rightVector = glm::normalize(rightVector);
    cameraPosition += (rightVector * movementScalar);
    break;





}
}




void SpecialInput(int key, int x, int y)
{
switch (key)
{


case GLUT_KEY_LEFT:

    rz += 1.0;
    break;

case GLUT_KEY_RIGHT:
    rz -= 1.0f;
    break;
case GLUT_KEY_UP:
    rz2 -= 1.0f;
    break;

case GLUT_KEY_DOWN:
    rz2 += 1.0f;
    break;
}

glutPostRedisplay();
}

void MouseClickCallbackFunction(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
// Handle mouse clicks
switch (button) {

    if (state == GLUT_DOWN) {
case GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON:
    std::cout << "Mouse X: " << x << "Mouse Y: " << y << std::endl;

    break;
case GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON:
    std::cout << "Mouse X: " << x << "Mouse Y: " << y << std::endl;
    if (x < windowWidth / 2 && y < windowHeight / 2) {

        viewport = 3;
        std::cout << "Viewport =" << viewport<<std::endl;
    }
    if (x > windowWidth / 2 && y < windowHeight / 2) {
        viewport = 4;
        std::cout << "Viewport ="<< viewport << std::endl;
    }
    if (x > windowWidth / 2 && y > windowHeight / 2) {
        viewport = 2;
        std::cout << "Viewport ="<< viewport << std::endl;
    }
    if (x < windowWidth / 2 && y > windowHeight / 2) {
        viewport = 1;
        std::cout << "Viewport ="<< viewport << std::endl;
    }
    break;
    }




}
}
```

So I'm probably screwed since this is supposed to be due midnight, and the teacher didn't tell us enough information to complete this properly. I would appreciate help if someone could tell me how to select a specific viewport to transform with left click, that would then transform the camera by the arrow keys.

Comment: I would recommend against using the fixed pipeline. Use shades instead.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you know everything you need to do that. OpenGL won't save the state for you. Instead you are responsible for remembering the state and transferring it to OpenGL for each viewport you render. So define:

```
struct ViewportState {
    int vp[2], vs[2]; // position annd size of the viewport on screen
    vec3 pos; // camera position in the world
    vec3 rot; // euler angles of camera rotation
};

ViewportState viewports[number_of_viewports];
int active_viewport = 0;
```

Write a function to calculate the view matrix of a viewport:

```
mat4 ViewMatrix(const ViewportState &vp)
{
    // build a view matrix m based on vp.pos and vp.rot
    return m;
}
```

Now use these  during rendering:

```
void DisplayViewport(int i)
{
    const ViewportState &vp = viewports[i];
    glViewport(vp.vp[0], vp.vp[1], vp.vs[0], vp.vs[1]);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    if(i == active_vieport)
    {
        // draw a highlighted border around viewport
    }

    // load ViewMatrix(vp)
    // draw the actual 3d content of the viewport
}

void DisplayCallbackFunction(void)
{
    // ...
    for(int i = 0; i < nviewports; ++i)
        DisplayViewport(i);
    //...
}
```

The keyboard and the mouse will modify the active viewport:

```
void KeyboardCallbackFunction(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    // ...
    case 'w':
        viewports[active_viewport].pos -= (ViewMatrix(viewports[active_viewport]) * vec4(0,0,movementScalar,1)).xyz;
        break;

    case 'a':
        viewports[active_viewport].pos -= (ViewMatrix(viewports[active_viewport]) * vec4(movementScalar,0,0,1)).xyz;
        break;
    // ...
}
```

To activate a different viewport:

```
void MouseClickCallbackFunction(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
    // iterate over viewports, find the one within x/y coordinates and set active_viewport accordingly
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 choices.

1. Render your viewport scene to a frame buffer backed by a texture. Then render the texture to the screen
2. Transform your scene from viewport space to screen space using matrices. To prevent yourself drawing out the box use a scissor test to clip to the viewport